# Anaconda only comes with anaconda prompt

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, jupyter, conda, windows-update

I used to have the whole anaconda package on my Windows 10 computer (an HP Envy) until recently, Windows 10 updated and the update caused problems so I restored the previous version of windows (keep in mind, I installed Anaconda about 3 updates ago so restoring should not have caused a problem).  A few days later, I tried to use Jupyter but "jupyter notebook" no longer launched Jupyter when typed into PowerShell.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling with all different preferences (i.e. me only, all users, PATH, no PATH, etc.) but it still installs as only the anaconda prompt.  When I type conda --version in PowerShell, my error says "The term conda is not recognized" ...
Does anyone have any suggestions? I really need to use Jupyter.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8266, it might be related to your anti-virus program. Did Python or conda land in quarantine?